# Why isn't JUnit's assertTrue being resolved?

Tags: gradle, junit

I have a project that follows the standard Maven structure:

- project

  - src

    - main

      - java
    - test

      - java

In some classes, assertTrue is able to be resolved, and in others it cannot be resolved.

I took the static import from the class (in the src/java/test directory) that is resolving and pasted it into the class that can't resolve assertTrue (in the src/java/main directory) and that didn't resolve it.

So using `import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;` doesn't work.

Using `Assert.assertTrue` doesn't work either.

**Edit:**

One thing that I didn't make clear in the initial post is that this isn't a standard Java project with unit tests. The project is the integration test framework for another Java program. So all the code within this project exists to test the functionality of another program using the external REST API. Hence why I had a Junit assertion outside the test folder. Granted there may still be an opportunity to clean that up.

Comment: i didn't downvote. but it would seem like a better idea to not have code under main have a dependency on JUnit, and find a different way to implement your assertion, whether using the language keyword or your own utility.

Comment: That makes sense. I may rework that particular part of the code. My main purpose of putting this up was to document that how the dependencies are specified may affect the scope so to speak.

All other questions I saw about assertTrue not resolving only mentioned the static import. That wasn't enough in my case.

Answer (score 3):

So the issue was in my `build.gradle` file that I had specified the junit dependency as a `testCompile` dependency. Meaning that it would only be apply to classes within the src/test directory. So to resolve my issue, I changed the build.gradle to use `compile('junit:junit:4.12')`.

I could have also moved the file that wasn't resolving into the src/test directory, but the file didn't logically belong there.